# Google Analytics external link code not working

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

Our current external link code hasn't been working properly, so I was asked to draw up a new set. This is code that I pulled off another website, but it looks as if it works properly (save the $().ready that it was missing). I am well aware that Google advises that you put the onclick manually into each external link, but there's too many to do so feasibly on my site, so I'm resorting to JQuery as a catch-all. I have been unable to implement this on more than one page that is normally inaccessible by users (due to supervisory paranoia), and as a result have been having to activate in-page analytics to view the stats for that page. No clicks on external links register, though I have discovered (using alerts) that the _gaq.push at least fires. Here is the code (now fixed):

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("a").on('click',function(e){
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        if (e.currentTarget.host != window.location.host) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outbound Link', e.currentTarget.host, url, 0]);
            if (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey || this.target=="_blank") {
                 var newtab = true;
            }
            if (!newtab) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 setTimeout('document.location = "' + url + '"', 100);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The (!newtab) if is to ensure that the _gaq.push fires by using a timeout. Any ideas to fix it?

Edit: It might be worth noting that this is an external file.

Edit2: The code has had the error corrected for easy copy/pasting of others who would like to use it. Many thanks to Mike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing obvious wrong with your code. Instead of trying to verify the events via in-page analytics, I'd try to check the `__utm.gif` tracking pixel request. A few different ways of doing this are:

- The Network tab in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome Developer Tools.
- A web debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
- The Google Analytics debugging script [ga_debug.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#gaDebug) will log tracking requests & errors.
- [Google Analytics Tracking Code Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) is a Chrome extension that enables ga_debug.js.

My preferences are to use the Chrome Developer Tools or Fiddler.

The analytics code on the page probably has a `_trackPageview`, so as the page loads you'll see an initial __utm.gif.

When _trackEvent fires, you should see a new __utm.gif request being made. Things to check out in the __utm.gif URL include:

- utme=5(Outbound Link*host*URL) -- _trackEvent parameters
- utmac=UA-1234567-8 --  the analytics UID

Correction -- minor bug: `target=="_blank"` should be `this.target=="_blank"` in the check for opening in a new window.

Comment: Thanks. _utm.gif shows up on the page when it loads. However, everything--and I mean everything--vanishes in the network tab when clicking on a link. Is there anything in particular I should be looking at on the _utm.gif URL? After doing some basic research on it, it seems like there's very little it can actually tell me to do with this.

Also, the GA debugger doesn't really work for me. The sites where I am going to either don't have GA, or they don't have a current version (either way, there's no response from the debugger). Perhaps I'm using it wrong?

Comment: The reason everything vanishes is because a new page is loading in the current window. To prevent this, in chrome, using the developer tools, you can add a target='_blank' attribute to one of the links which will cause the link to open in a new window. I added some additional info about the _trackEvent __utm.gif

Comment: Sorry for the late response--got pulled off this and on to other things. The site I'm working on has a policy that all external links go to new tabs, so each of the ones that I'm testing already has "target='_blank'" as a qualifier. However, for an odd reason (possibly to do with this code, as it's only on this particular page) the "target" attribute no longer works (no new tabs, same page). Obviously, this is making the _utm.gif pretty difficult to track. Any suggestions as to what might be causing this? The page in question is [right here](http://library.uis.edu/sandbox201209.html).

Comment: One bug: `target=="_blank"` should be `this.target=="_blank"` -- Fix that and it'll open the links in a new window & you should be able to verify the __utm.gif tracking.

Comment: That's exactly what appears to have done it. New _utm.gifs spawn with the clicks. Now we just play the waiting game to see if it works properly. Thanks a bunch for sticking through with this.